# Отключить превью ссылки в телеграм боте (php)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

По умолчанию, если прикрепляешь в сообщение ссылку, то телеграм подгружает небольшое превью сайта в нижней части сообщения.

Есть ли возможность отключить эту функцию при отправке сообщения?

```
$the_link = "<a href='https://example.com'>ссылка</a>";

sendTelegram('sendMessage', array(
 'chat_id' => $chat_id,
 'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
 'text' => $the_link));
```

Comment: вам нужен `disable_web_page_preview = True`

Comment: @oleksandrigo спаибо! а куда именно его вписать в моей конструкции?

Comment: я в пехе разбираюсь плохо, но думаю что-то типа этого `'disable_web_page_preview' => True` доп параметром

Comment: Да, спасибо, сработало! подставил, работает!) Можете "ответить на вопрос", я вам галочку выдам)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так

```
sendTelegram('sendMessage', array(
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'text' => $the_link,
    'disable_web_page_preview' => True));
```